# Get object by ID in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I noticed that our senior developer uses following code for retrieving entity by ID:

```
@Override
public Source get(Long id) {
    Session session = getSession();
    if( session == null )
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    final Source source = (Source)session.load(Source.class, id);
    Hibernate.initialize(source);
    return source;
}
```

What is benefit of this code?

Why not simply writing

```
return (Soruce) getSession().get(Source.class, id);
```

Comment: I guess this was developed with older hibernate version. I think hibernate 3.4 onwards supports getSession().

Comment: Maybe he also wanted to keep the code "clean" according to the book "Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin instead of writing more than one statement on one line of code.

Answer (score 11):

Those 2 pieces of code aren't equivalent.

```
session.load(Source.class, id);
```

will **throw an exception** if there is no `Source` entity with the identifier `id`.

```
getSession().get(Source.class, id);
```

will **return null** if there is no `Source` entity with the identifier `id`.